# Removing redundant constituent strings from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I saw a question that was posted yesterday about how a list like such:

```
my_list = ["lol hi there", "hi", "i like", "i like apples", "goodbye"]
```

could be converted into:

```
my_list = ["lol hi there", "i like apples", "goodbye"]
```

where the strings like `"hi"` and `"i like"` are removed from `my_list`, due to how `"hi"` and `"i like"` are found in the strings `"lol hi there"` and `"i like apples"` respectively. They are removed from the list purely because of their occurence in any of the other strings found in the list, regardless of index within the list, or position within the string.

Another example would be where:

```
my_list1 = ["hello", "he", "go", "goodbye", "good", ]
```

would be converted to:

```
my_list1 = ["hello", "goodbye"]
```

due to the recurrence of `"he"` in `"hello"`, and `"go"`, as well as `"good"`, in `"goodbye"`.

I tried using the following method for this:

```
import re

my_list = ["lol hi there", "hi", "i like", "i like apples", "goodbye"]

for x in my_list:
    for y in my_list:
        if x != y:
            if len(x) < len(y):
                if re.search(x, y):
                    my_list.pop(my_list.index(x))
            else:
                if re.search(y, x):
                    my_list.pop(my_list.index(y))
print(my_list)
```

which returned me what I desired. The user had deleted their question, but I want to know a more concise way of approaching this. Could someone lend me a hand?

Comment: what is the criteria of a 'small'/'redundant' string that needs to be removed?

Comment: @moys It refers to a string that is already found in another string in the list. For example, "hi" and "i like" are removed from the list due to their recurrence in the strings "lol hi there" and "i like apples" respectively.

Comment: What would be that output when `["hi", "lol hi there", "i like apples","i like", "goodbye"]`?

Comment: Your main job is to state the question in a clear and unambiguous way. You rarely can do that by casting the question in terms of an example (though examples are helpful). You need to state the criteria for whether an element of the array is to be kept. I'm guessing that you are not keeping "I like" because the next element begins "I like". What if "I like apples" came later in the array or before "I like"? Presumably you are not keeping "hi" because that word appeared in the string before. Would you have kept it if the first element were "A high mountain"? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Ch3steR It would by `my_list = ["lol hi there", "i like apples", "goodbye"]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Alright, I'll edit my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about using regex you can use the `in` operator.

```
my_list = ["lol hi there", "hi", "i like", "i like apples", "goodbye"]
filtered_list = []
for i,si in enumerate(my_list):
    # search each element against every other element in the list, j != i ensures it doesnt compare to self.
    inlist = any( [ si in xi for j, xi in enumerate(my_list) if j != i] )
    if not inlist:
        filtered_list.append( si )
print( filtered_list )
```

Or if you prefer it all on one line:

```
filtered_list = [ si for i, si in enumerate( my_list ) if not any( [si in sii for j, sii in enumerate(my_list) if j != i] )]
print( filtered_list )
```